# adding timeout to jena (for sparql) using dbpedia as end point?

Tags: java, timeout, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I would like to know whether there is a way to use Jena to do a sparql query through dbpedia and using the timeout setting given in http://dbpedia.org/sparql (if you see this page, you could see that there is a way to set the timeout there), this is needed since I would like to make a big query and I have tried several times (via the page) that without setting the timeout, I cannot get the result (it is always a transaction timeout exception)

edited: I use java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute your query, I guess you're using :

```
QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(String service, Query query)
```

One thing you could try is:

```
QueryEngineHTTP objectToExec=QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql",YOUR_QUERY);
objectToExec.addParam("timeout","5000"); //5 sec
resultset=objectToExec.execSelect();
```

It seems that `QueryEngineHTTP` implements `QueryExecution` which has an `addParam` method. There's no description of that method but I'd assume that adds a parameter to the HTTP request.

Let me know if it works !!

**Edited**
to fix error actually it was the other way around ... `QueryEngineHTTP` implements `QueryExecution`

Comment: there's no method such as addParam in QueryExecution

Comment: You're right. I got it the other way around. Look at the new edition of the answer I think is right know. Also consider accepting answers an up-vote things in stackoverflow otherwise you'll get a very low acceptance ratio and people will not spend time helping you. Just an advice. To accept an answer click on V sign besides the answer.

Comment: That's work! Thank you very much. However I still wonder why they have to inherit it somewhere :D

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, service) ;
qexec.setTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
String result = ResultSetFormatter.asText(results);
```

If if the timeout limit it reached then a org.apache.jena.query.QueryCancelledException is thrown.